# Power Automate runtime parameters possible in expressions?

Tags: parameters, runtime, power-automate

I have a flow where I'm attempting to show the questions and answers to a survey. Both are stored in SharePoint lists.
The answers are stored in a single row, one field per response (the response is a single-valued choice).
The questions are stored one per row, with a column showing the question and a column for the field name.
So for instance the response list has a field named `Risk_x0020_Physical_x0020_Enviro` (the displayed name is `Risk Physical Environment`).

The question has a row where the `Choice Field Name` field has the value `Risk_x0020_Physical_x0020_Enviro` and the Question field is the wording of the question the responder answers.

In the flow, I need to output an HTML table of the questions and answers for a single response.

As far as I can see the expression would be something like:

```
@{@{body('Get_Response')}[@{items('Apply_to_each')['Field']}]}
```

Where the `Get_Response` step gets the relevant response list row and the `Apply_to_each` steps through the rows of the questions list.

This doesn't work though - it won't even allow me to save it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it's pretty complicated:

1. Get all the questions using Get Items on the list.
2. Use Parse JSON to extract the fields and values from this list.
3. Use a Select operation to get the field names, questions etc. in a way that Power Automate will recognize.
4. Use an "Apply to each" on the resulting array. In this operation, get the value for the response to that question using a expression like: "body('Get_item_from_Responses_list')[items('For_each_Risk')['Field']]['Value']", where 'Field' is the field name you used in the Select. Note that if a question is optional, the value might not exist, so you should have a fallback value to set the value to (using an execute on failed from the previous step). You can then append this value to the array that you're building.
5. At the end of this, you can build the HTML table using the "Create HTML Table" action. You can format this table, especially if you are careful about creating the headers; there are some articles on doing this.

The advantage of doing this is that you can change the wording of the questions by changing the values in the SharePoint list as opposed to editing and updating the Power App. You still can't add questions though.
Disadvantage is that it's more complicated to deal with of course.
The impetus for this solution was that the questionnaire was planned to be in Microsoft Forms, but there were too many questions. As it is, Power Automate is warning me that there are too many controls on the form. I suppose I could remove that by doing it as a multi-page (multi-screen) app, but performance seems OK to date with 38 questions (each of which has a choice and a comment field).